# XML ElementTree Parsing difficulties when providing directory of XML file

Tags: elementtree, python-2.6

I am trying to iterate over elements of an XML.  I have several log folders and each folder has a large text file with an XML structure embedded within it.  I read the text file, find the XML start and finish points capture the XML section and save as a separate XML file within the log folder, though I don't necessarily need to save as a file.

Using Python 2.6 (for restrictive reasons) I have a function that works well when ElementTree is passed the file string like **'rx_XML.xml'** (**provided my script is working from the same directory**).  But when passing the file path like **'/my/log/dir/rx_XML.xml'** to the function ElementTree can't find the file and I get the following error:

```
self._parser.Parse("", 1) # end of data
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Unfortunately I am restricted to using Python 2.6 and its default libraries, which makes things much more difficult.  Here's my XML parsing function:

```
import os, sys
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

def xmlDictionary(xmlfile):
    #xmlfile value works ok with filename e.g. 'rx_XML.xml'
    #xmlfile fails with directory plus filename e.g. '/my/log/dir/rx_XML.xml'
    root = ElementTree(file=xmlfile)

    #Create an iterator
    iter = root.getiterator()

    xmlDict = {}
    #Iterate
    for element in iter:
        #iterate over elements, drop things into dictionary for use later
```

If any use, here's parts of my code to extract the XML data from a large text file:

```
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/my/log/dir/'):
    for file in filenames:
        if file.endswith('textfile.txt'):
            file = os.path.join(dirname,file)           
            with open(file, "r") as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                for line in lines:
                    if ('<xmlfile>' in line):
                        #XML section found, create a new file
                        rxfile = os.path.join(dirname, 'rx_XML.xml')                        rxoutfile = open(rxfile, 'w')
                        rxoutfile.write(line)
                        #start writing to file
                        ....

                    if (line.startswith('</xmlfile>')):
                        rxoutfile.write(line)
                        rxoutfile.close 
                        rxDict = xmlDictionary('rx_XML.xml')
```

Comment: That's odd, given that `/my/dir/rx_XML.xml` is an absolute path to an existing XML file with a valid structure. Can this be confirmed?

Comment: "no element found" is not the same as "file not found". The error message indicates that the file you are trying to parse might be empty. Can you print it, instead of parsing it? What do you get?

Comment: I added a print statement to check xmlfile for just the filename and then the absolute path plus filename, which prints the strings 'rx_XML.xml' and '/my/log/dir/rx_XML.xml' respectively, but the absolute path attempt fails to parse/find the XML

Comment: Try `with open(xmlfile, 'rb') as f: root = ElementTree(file=f)`.